# What does "slotting in around" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the book [Zom-B Bride by Darren Shine](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rvt9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=Slotting+in+around+the+forces+of+good+and+evil+were+a+variety+of+other+groups+and+individuals&source=bl&ots=1p83qcm7bW&sig=ZtlTLu0mPccwtpqS-8dmHrFzNSE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxpcjqkZjKAhWK2SYKHTTGDJsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Slotting%20in%20around%20the%20forces%20of%20good%20and%20evil%20were%20a%20variety%20of%20other%20groups%20and%20individuals&f=false), I encounterd this sentence:

> Slotting in around the forces of good and evil were a variety of other
>   groups and individuals.

I am not completely sure what does "slotting in around" means? Is it a common expression that I haven't heard of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context in the surrounding passage of the given book, it has the third sense given in [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/slot_2):

> to fit well with a group of people or a way of life (*The new members of the team slotted in easily.*)

The complete sense of the sentence seems to be that these other groups (as mentioned in the next sentence- i.e. the Army and KKK) were fulfilling some role in this world, beyond simple good and evil.